# How to fix this - Maven dependency added but import unresolved in intellij?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

After a recent merge in a repo, the maven file was updated for adding aws bucket access.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

The above dependency is present in my pom.xml file.
But still,  I am getting the following error :

> cannot resolve symbol **SDKGlobalConfiguration**

for the following lines

```
import com.amazonaws.SDKGlobalConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
```

list of imports used :

```
import com.amazonaws.SDKGlobalConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;
```

Update : 
Updated  the complete list of imports used below.

Answer (score 2):

It belongs to submodule.

Add more specific:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

If you decided to use SDK version 1 you have to add dependencies for individual services as far as you don't import BOM.

Actually, BOM is recommended method. So add the following:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.298</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: replaced my previous dependency with -core. But it resulted in an even worse result

The above solution made the following  imports unresolvable in addition to my previous issue 

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;

Comment: @Arthul, it's fine because of you have to pick all you needed AWS SDK modules and set up the accordingly. <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>

Comment: I added the BOM dependency, but still unable to resolve one import : 

import com.amazonaws.SDKGlobalConfiguration;


Can you please update your answer and help me out ?